# 2004 Volvo S60 D5 diesel (Euro 3): clouds of black smoke

Tags: volvo, s60

My S60 has a developing problem where considerable quantities of soot are emitted from the exhaust. Upon first startup, cold engine, the smoke is nearly entirely absent. When the engine reaches some particular temperature (normally at consistently the same point on my journey home/into work) the message area shows "Engine Service Required". Shortly after this point in my commute there's a long uphill, and if I take it in 3rd gear at around 2000 rpm there's so much soot flying out of the exhaust it causes the trailing car's automatic headlight lights to turn on (if it has the facility, of course).

I've also noticed that there's a periodic hesitation in the power delivery -
 again going up that hill in 3rd at about 2000 rpm, the power surges on and off slightly, every second or so. Generally the power delivery is poorer than it was, with the car sounding a little more "asthmatic/wheezy" than it used to

Fault codes read recently indicated fuel pressure issues, sometimes too low or high, and a code from the turbo control system (i think it was "6805 boost pressure control fault") but it doesn't cause limp mode (in its current manifestation)

A local garage said they didn't find any obvious intercooler or hose leaks but turbos aren't their speciality, and recommended another garage further away with more experience in forced induction

From the symptoms described, are there any causes more likely than others for the soot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one turned out to be a relatively common problem on D5s; the intercooler had split and boost pressure was being lost. Quite why the first shop didn't pick this up I've no idea, but having replaced the intercooler there's now a pronounced difference in extra power delivery and reduced emissions of soot

Answer (score 2):

Does it have EGR - exhaust gas recirculation? If so, this could be part or all of the problem. Sounds similar to other cars with egr faults.

Comment: I'll get it checked out; it's been on my mind as all my other diesel cars have had EGR related issues in the past few years, but this one behaves slightly differently..